# How to connect an Azure Webjob to Azure Keyvault?

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, azure-webjobs, azure-keyvault

I can't seem to figure out how to connect my webjob to keyvault to use the client side encryption features... The problem is more with setting up the keyvault, in theory I know what functions to use within the webjob once I am connected to the keyvault. I seem to need some sort of connection or identification string which identifies my webjob as a program which is allowed to access my keyvault but I can't find that string anywhere so I'm really not sure how to do it at this point...

If it makes a difference I am working in .NET/C# and I am attempting to add encryption to a working webjob which accesses tables and queues, the table is to be encrypted but the queue doesn't matter.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you're asking, are you having a specific problem with some aspect? have you followed the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/key-vault-developers-guide/) is it failing at any particular part? In you need to have defined an Active Directory application to obtain credentials to pass to keyvault to access keys stored there.

Comment: OK it is the active directory part that is confusing me, I was reading a different set of documentation (Azure has way too many different sets of documentation...) but the video on the page you just linked is pretty much exactly what I was having a hard time with so I think I can figure it out now thanks.